# How can we predict random non-balanced events?

Tags: predictive-models, prediction

Prediction is the ability to statistically foretell the occurrence of future events by learning from historical data.

In all the cases, if we have a large enough sample of data on how people behaved in the past, we can predict their behaviors with a reasonable degree of confidence. But, how can we predict events that are random and rare.

I am working on study to predict earth-quack. I am doing this study with a limited resources, so I don't have enough data about geology. I want to model this problem statistically based on what happened before.

As first approach, I was thinking to use poisson model, so I count earth-quack that happened in specific place, calculate the next events using this model, how can we add a trick to make sure that this event would happen.

My questions are:

- Is it good approach to use counting model to tackle this problem ?
- Can you, please, suggest any other effective ways to tackle this problem ?